# For a morphism of $k$-schemes $f:X\to Y$, when does the smoothness of $X$ imply the smoothness of $Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

A part of [Lemma 05AX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05AX) in the Stacks Project states the following:

> Let $k$ be a field. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes locally of finite type over $k$. If $X$ is smooth over $k$ and $f$ is flat and surjective, then $Y$ is smooth over $k$.

Are there any similar situations where the smoothness of $X$ implies the smoothness of $Y$ with the flatness condition relaxed or replaced with a "more geometric" condition?

The reason why I ask such a question is that I do not find the flatness condition to be nearly as straightforward as the smoothness condition (this is only an opinion), yet it seems so necessary since examples like the one suggested by Mariano in the comments exist.

Comment: 1. When citing the Stacks Project, please link to the result and use the [tags](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tags) as references: these tags are guaranteed to **never change**, whereas the numbering between versions can differ. 2. Please make your title more specific. "Asking for a variation of a theorem" could be about literally anything.

Comment: The map t \mapsto (t^2,t^3) maps the line to a cuspidal cubic, so not always.

Comment: This question is quite vague. Do you think you might be able to make it a bit more pointed?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I hope my question is clearer now.

Comment: @StillALittleChild Do you mind clarifying though, as smooth morphisms are flat. Anyways, let me mention a result in the sort of opposite direction. Namely, I think you can agree that any reasonable $f$ should have the following property: for every closed point $y$ of $Y$, one has that $\dim f^{-1}(y)=\dim X -\dim Y$. In other words, fibers over closed points of the image have the expected dimension. Then, such such morphisms you have that $Y$ is smooth if and only if $f$ is flat. Indeed, the one direction you already cited, and the other direction is so-called 'miracle flatness'.

Comment: So, I don't think you can really escape flatness hypotheses here (at least not morally).